# Ramsey Number R(3,3,4)

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

How much is known about the Ramsey number R(3,3,4)? There is a trivial upper bound of 34, but are any tighter bounds known?

Answer (score 19):

According to the reference 1 below to earlier work of the authors in this paper [here](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~spr/PUBL/paper44.pdf), it is known that
$$
30\leq R(3,3,4)\leq 31
$$

**Edit:** A more recent paper, by Codish, Frank, Itzhakov and Miller,  available [here](http://dcs.gla.ac.uk/~alice/papers/ramseyConstraints2016.pdf) has shown that $R(3,3,4)=30.$ Thanks to @Julian.

1. Piwakowski, K., and Radziszowski, S. P., Journal of Combinatorial Mathematics and Combinatorial Computing, 27:135-141, 1998.

Comment: Actually, $R(3,3,4)=30$. See http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~alice/papers/ramseyConstraints2016.pdf